# PostgreSQL query on a timestamp array

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a table with a varchar array column that contains timestamp data. How can I query this table with a date range?

Something like this:

```
select * 
from events 
where any(occurrences::timestamp[]) between '2013-11-30' and '2013-12-01'
```

Comment: Please supply the table definition and some sample data including the expected output. Btw: You should never (really: never) store timestamps or dates as a string. And the problem you have now is a direct result of that wrong design.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/51818/1 its a invalid result. The were condition need to run at same element.

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH tbl AS(
    SELECT *, unnest(occurrences::timestamp[]) itm
    FROM events 
)
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM tbl
WHERE 
  itm BETWEEN '2013-10-01 00:00:00 UTC'::timestamp AND '2013-11-01 00:00:00 UTC' ::timestamp
```

Comment: That's probably a separate question, but is there an index on timestamp[] that would support such a query?